# kde plot for interpreting the correlation

Tags: visualization, feature-engineering

i have created some new features for my model. I found people use kde plot to find out the correlation between the created feature and the target variable, but I am not really sure how to find the correlation from kde.

Any help on how to interpret the correlation from kde plot will very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CoreyLevinson on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/discussion/62669) answered my question. I am simply adding the explaination.

The kde shows the density of the feature for each value of the target. There are usually 2 colored humps representing the 2 values of TARGET. If the humps are well-separated and non-overlapping, then there is a correlation with the TARGET. If the humps are overlapping a lot, then that means the feature is not well-correlated with the TARGET, because the TARGET is equally as common on those values of the feature.